# Algebraic rules for a fundamental polygon

Tags: general-topology

If we have a 2d surface, we can give it a plane model with a sequence of letters corresponding to gluing instructions for it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_polygon for examples.

So if we have a sequence like (a^-1,b,a,b^-1,...) what kinds of algebraic rules can we use to simplify it into a simpler form? (Stuff like a^-1*a cancels etc)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule you cited is the only easy one. The real simplifications come from doing things like cutting the polygon on some diagonal (labelling the new edges, say, $p$ and $p^{-1}$ and then gluing the two pieces together along some OTHER pair of edges (say $d$ and $d^{-1}$) which appear in the two parts. This corresponds to something like this:

$$
abcd'cda'b'ee' \to \\
abcd'p' cda'b'ee'p \to \\
abc'a'b'ee'pcp'
$$

where it's easiest to see this by drawing the polygon, cutting it along the diagonal from the vertex between $e'$ and $a$ to the vertex between $d'$ and $c$, labeling that diagonal "$p$" on both sides, and reassembling so that the two "$d$" edges match up, and then reading off the gluing-sequence from this newly assembled polygon. (I'm using $x'$ for $x^{-1}$ here, for simpler typing.)